# PHP mkdir working on local machine but not on remote machine

Tags: php, mkdir

I want to create a folder using PHP and used this simple code I got on the Internet.

```
if (!file_exists ($_SESSION['foo']))
{
    mkdir ($_SESSION['foo'], 0775, true);
}
```

This works on my local Windows server (Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.5) but it isn't working on the remote Fedora server (Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.2). Does anyone have any ideas about why it might not be working? If it helps, I don't have root access on the remote server but I can definitely create folders through the command line using the `mkdir` command.

I also tried

```
if (!file_exists ($_SESSION['foo']))
{
    mkdir ($_SESSION['foo'], 0775;
}
```

This didn't help either.

Comment: you need to check if the root folder permission is writable by web server.

Comment: Why the root folder? The server is not at /var/www but it is at ~/public_html

Comment: root in the sense the root directory from where your trying to create a folder

Comment: Did you check your www-data user has write privilege on parent folder where you are trying to create new one? Folder where you want to create new files and folders should have drwxrwxr-x flags if you use ls- l command in cli

Comment: This script runs at `~/public_html/some_folder`. public_html has permissions of 775 and some_folder has 775 as well. And the new folder should be created at `~/public_html/some_folder/foo`

Comment: @IvanHušnjak It has the very same drwxrwxr-x i.e. 775

Comment: Changing the permissions of some_folder to 777 worked. But isn't this a security issue? Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving the current directory 777 permissions.

---

However, I feel this might be a security issue and would be glad to know if there is a better solution